# Need to find the update schedule name in Azure update management postscript

Tags: azure-automation

I am using a `powershell` runbook as `PostScript` to send the azure update management result using this code.

```
$queryResults = Invoke-AzureRmOperationalInsightsQuery -WorkspaceId $WorkspaceId -Query "UpdateRunProgress | take 4000"  -Timespan (New-TimeSpan -Hours 6).
```

Problem here is it is giving all results available for last six hours. I need to somehow get the update schedule name inside runbook, so that I can filter out the results matching current update schedule name when the runbook runs as a `postscript`.